# Wordpress WPML - set currency programmatically

Tags: php, wordpress, wpml

I'm using WPML and WooCommerce Multilingual with multicurrency setting. I'm detecting geolocation of visitor via `geoplugin.net` to set up site language.

I want to set up currency also and here's a question:

Is there a way to set up currency programmatically in WooCommerce Multilingual? I tried `do_action('wcml_switch_currency', $_curr);` where `$_curr = 'GBP';`' with no luck :/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out via `filter`, this is example:

```
add_filter('wcml_client_currency', 'wcml_custom_currency');
function wcml_custom_currency($current){
    return 'GBP'; 
}
```